# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/kish')

Tags: android, xml

I want give id as `@android:id/kish` but it shows

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with                        value '@android:id/kish').

but the above `@android:id/text1` works

```
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Dummy content. -->
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
                <TextView android:id="@android:id/kish"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />



            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

**IMAGES**

[image: xml errorpic]
[image: The run time error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@android:id/text1 is already defined in **ids.xml**.
ids.xml is generally used to declare the id's that you use for the views in the layouts.
So, you have to declare your `@android:id/kish` in ids.xml
Or you can declare like that `android:id="@+id/kish"`

Comment: which file i shuld declare android:id="@+id/kish"

Comment: you have to declare this instead of @android:id/kish in your layout :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating views dynamically, predefined id's in ids.xml gives the possibility to reference a newly created view. After you use the setId(id) method you can access the view as if it had been defined in XML. This is default ids of Android which you can find from this path "USER_DIRECTORY/android-sdk/platforms/android-23/data/res/values/ids.xml" where `@android:id/text1` is also part of that. So,if you want to give id to any view then instead of using that, use like below to assign id.

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

Comment: sorry i really cannot understand where the path is to initialise the id..can u send me a scrren shot of it

Comment: To use in your view you can use as i mentioned, `android:id="@+id/textView"`